# ReadWriteMany volumes on kubernetes with terabytes of data

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

We want to deploy a k8s cluster which will run ~100 IO-heavy pods at the same time. They should all be able to access the same volume.

What we tried so far:

- CephFS

  - was very complicated to set up. Hard to troubleshoot. In the end, it crashed a lot and the cause was not entirely clear.
- Helm NFS Server Provisioner

  - runs pretty well, but when IO peaks a single replica is not enough. We could not get multiple replicas to work at all.
- MinIO

  - is a great tool to create storage buckets in k8s. But our operations require fs mounting. That is theoretically possible with s3fs, but since we run ~100 pods, we would need to run 100 s3fs sidecars additionally. Thats seems like a bad idea.

There has to be some way to get 2TB of data mounted in a GKE cluster with relatively high availability?

Firestorage seems to work, but it's a magnitude more expensive than other solutions, and with a lot of IO operations it quickly becomes infeasible.

---

*I contemplated creating this question on server fault, but the k8s community is a lot smaller than SO's.*

Comment: Are you using Google Kubernetes Engine? Have you tried using a storage class other than default in a PersistentVolumeClaim?

Comment: Here is a great blog on storage performance https://vitobotta.com/2019/08/06/kubernetes-storage-openebs-rook-longhorn-storageos-robin-portworx/

Comment: Did you try Cloud Filestore - https://cloud.google.com/filestore? This would support your use case however I've heard that others have trouble getting really good throughput from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a definitive answer as of Jan 2020, at least for our usecase:

```
| Solution        | Complexity | Performance | Cost           |
|-----------------|------------|-------------|----------------|
| NFS             | Low        | Low         | Low            |
| Cloud Filestore | Low        | Mediocre?   | Per Read/Write |
| CephFS          | High*      | High        | Low            |

* You need to add an additional step for GKE: Change the base image to ubuntu
```

I haven't benchmarked Filestore myself, but I'll just go with [stringy05](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420941/stringy05)'s response: *others have trouble getting really good throughput from it*

Ceph could be a lot easier if it was supported by Helm.

Comment: Why have you discarded entirely using SSD storage with dynamically provisioned PersistentVolumes? Is there some reason regarding your use case that discards this entirely? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/ssd-pd

Comment: It says ReadWriteMany in the title. Directly connecting disks only allows RWOnce.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that fact.

Comment: On the pricing page it seems that Cloud Filestore will run at least $200/mo.  Their minimum volume size is 1TB and it costs at least $0.20/GB/mo.

Comment: @ckeeney Good point. If you're fine with HDDs, regular gcp disks are just $40/TB/month and way more flexible regarding size. Also very little operation cost.